# Spring Configuration Properties with DataSource (YML)

Tags: java, spring, configuration, datasource

I need to use a configuration properties outside my jar.
For this, I'm using a class to configurate:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"file:///C:/main.properties"})
public class YAMLConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.db-prod")
    public DataSource personDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    private String name;
    private String environment;
    private String datasource;
    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<>();

    // standard getters and setters
```

My main.properties works perfectly when I use inside my program. But I want that this outside, because I want to change when i want.

My Spring class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class PsuInfoToolApplication {

    @Autowired
    private static YAMLConfig config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PsuInfoToolApplication.class, args);

    }
```

But it doesn't work, seems the file doesn't configure dataSource:
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

How can i do? I want to do a configuration file outside my jar and use for configurate my database directly, using a DataSource object.

Comment: See my edits @Traif

Comment: The `@ConfigurationProperties` are parsed very early in the proces. Your `@PropertySource` isn't processed yet. However you are using Spring Boot then why not use that to your advantage. You can simply specify which, additional, configuration files or directories it needs to scan. No need to hardcode that into an `@PropertySource` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Load the file from the classpath

You can load the property file from the classpath so that during the runtime automatically the file will be pickup.

**Example code:**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyPropWithinClasspath {

    private Properties prop = null;

    public MyPropWithinClasspath(){

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            this.prop = new Properties();
            is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample.properties");
            prop.load(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getPropertyValue(String key){
        return this.prop.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){

        MyPropWithinClasspath mpc = new MyPropWithinClasspath();
        System.out.println("db.host: "+mpc.getPropertyValue("db.host"));
        System.out.println("db.user: "+mpc.getPropertyValue("db.user"));
        System.out.println("db.password: "+mpc.getPropertyValue("db.password"));
    }
}
```

**OR**

> Load the file from environment variable

```
String extDir = System.getenv(EXTERNAL_DIR);
```

You can specify the path of the file in external.dir. So java will automatically recognize the variable. So that you can use the path from env variable and can load the file